# Show pending unapproved comments to Wordpress Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When an admin is logged in, viewing a page, it should show pending comments.

I thought this feature existed in Wordpress already, or maybe it was in a theme I used some time ago?

Is this a built-in feature anywhere, or would this require coding from scratch in PHP, using [wp_list_comments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments), rewriting in theme comments.php etc.?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be a built-in feature, not that I know of and I didn't find a plugin for this.  You can write a function for the theme that checks if the user is an admin then display the pending comments number.

If you are creating your own function to slip into a theme template try using parts of the code from http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/show-pending-comments-count/

This just updates the number in the admin but the functions should be similar.  Such as 
is_admin() then find and display the pending comments for that page.

Comments can be made with plugins or other functionality from a third party site so see what comments you are using first.

I don't know if this gets you off on the right foot but downloading and viewing that plugin did help me to understand this a bit better.  How I would approach it if I was trying this.

You certainly want to check and make sure they are an admin first.

Comment: That plugin's code is just a few lines of css, a few lines of Javascript to display on admin dashboard, I don't think anything like that would help to tap into the comments system when viewing a page, and show pending comments in thread view.